# How do I make my enemy's movement be staggered in Unity 2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

So, I'm working on a 2D RPG game project in Unity and right now I'm trying to implement a slime type enemy. I want its movement to be staggered, as if it were jumping around.
like this -> Jump - Pause - Jump - Pause - Jump - Pause (I think the slime in stardew valley behaves similarly if I remember correctly)

I've been searching around the internet but I haven't found any useful info yet. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Could you please explain what you have accomplished so far and provide enough code so others can better understand the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, we use [Coroutines](https://www.bing.com/videos/riverview/relatedvideo?q=coroutine%20basics%20untiy&mid=2D5E66AA988594EB71E02D5E66AA988594EB71E0&FORM=VIRE). They allow you to delay code for a set amount of seconds or until a certain condition is met. Below is a simple script that should get you going.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SlimeJump : MonoBehaviour
{
    //SerializeField tells unity to show the variable in the inspector even though the varible is private
    //Tooltip tells unity to show informational text when you hover over the variable in the inspector
    [SerializeField] [Tooltip("Amount In Secounds That The Slime Waits Before Jumping")] 
    private float jumpDelay;
    [SerializeField] [Tooltip("The Higher The Number, The Farther Up The Slime Will Jump")]
    private float verticalJumpForce;
    [SerializeField] [Tooltip("The Higher The Number, The Farther Right The Slime Will Jump")]
    private float horizontalJumpForce;
    [SerializeField]
    private Rigidbody2D slimeRigidbody;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Jump());
    }

    IEnumerator Jump()
    {
        //This Will Loop Until The The Script Is Destroyed 
        while (true)
        {.
            //Waits
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(jumpDelay);

            //Jumps
            slimeRigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * verticalJumpForce + Vector3.right * horizontalJumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer! Super helpful!